# Prove that a sequence is divergent (By definition - Epsilon-N Way)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, divergent-series

First, this is the question:

Prove (using epsilon-N definition) that the sequence $ a_n = \left<\sqrt{n}\right> $ is divergent.

Note: $ \left<x\right> = x- \lfloor x \rfloor$

**My question:**

I proved it by splitting it into cases: $L=0$ and $ L \neq 0 $

I wonder if there's a simpler and more beautiful proof to this question?

Thanks!

Comment: Clearly, $\langle \sqrt n \rangle  = 0$ whenever $\sqrt n$ is an integer, i.e. whenever $n$ is a square. This happens infinitely often, so if the limit exists, it has to be zero. (So there is no need to check the case $L \not= 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\langle \sqrt {n^2 -1}\rangle > \frac {n-1}{n}\\
\langle \sqrt {n^2}\rangle = 0$

For any $L$, there exist $n>4$ such that $| \sqrt {n} - \lfloor n\rfloor  - L| > \frac 14$

Or you could use Cauchy sequences.

A sequence is Cauchy if:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N>0: n,m>N \implies |a_n - a_m|<\epsilon$

So to show that it is not Cauchy say that there exist $m,n > N$ such that $|a_n-a_m|>\epsilon$

Comment: why is $⟨\sqrt{n^2−1}⟩>\frac{n−1}{n}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R) \; 0\le x-\lfloor x\rfloor <1$$

the possible limit would be in $[0,1]$.

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_{n^2}=0$$

Comment: Right, but how does this help me? Assuming i dont split it into cases. The other comment said that if it has a limit, It has to be 0. So how can i prove 0 is not the limit?

Answer (score 1):

For each $n \ge 1$ you have
$$\left( n + 1 - \frac 1n \right)^2 < n^2 + 2n < (n+1)^2$$
so that
$$ n + 1 - \frac 1n < \sqrt{n^2 + 2n} < n+1$$
and consequently
$$1 - \frac{1}{n} < \langle \sqrt{n^2 + 2n} \rangle < 1$$
for all $n$.  Thus $L = \lim a_n$, if it exists, must equal $1$.